# Button for 'add tag' field cut off and unusable in Chrome on SO

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Favorite and ignored tags edit boxes on Stack Apps getting clipped in Chrome](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109450/favorite-and-ignored-tags-edit-boxes-on-stack-apps-getting-clipped-in-chrome)

I feel dumb, but it took me a while to figure out that the add button was just hiding out of sight. Enter/return don't work either, so unless someone pulls up developer tools, adding new tags ain't happening.

[image]

Using Chrome 17.0.963.79 - default zoom

Comment: Are you running any user scripts?

Comment: Nothing that should change the layout.

Answer (score 2):

On chrome 18.0.1025.137 (beta) [image]

On chrome 19.0.1080.0 (canary) [image]

Wait a few milliseconds--Chrome will update itself ;).

Seriously though:

- What's your screen size?
- Is there a scrollbar on the bottom?
- Bigger screenshot please...

Edit:

Managed to hack-duplicate it by messing with devtools:
[image]

Comment: 1440 x 900 -- no scrollbar, overflow is hidden, haven't looked at the U-A stylesheet, but I suspect it's something about how it sizes the fields; bigger SH: http://i.imgur.com/rpAHm.png ; going to let Chrome update and see if it changes anything

Comment: @Greg: Managed to duplicate it.. For some reason it's being width-ed too much.. Quick fix: `javascript:$("#interestingTag,#ignoredTag").css("width","150px")`

Comment: Duplicate as in I hack-duplicated it-- it's not default behavior for me, I just injected some code.

Comment: @Greg: Could you just hit `Ctrl-shift-J` (JS console), and type `$("#interestingTag,#ignoredTag").css("width")` while on the main SO page? Let me know the result.

Comment: ----------------- 213px

Comment: Using windows 8 developer, so maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: @Greg: Hmm, I would have said that your tags had somehow messed up the auto-align (since the alignment does not seem to be set by default). But I fiddled with it and that doesn't seem to be the case. Of course, if it's Win8, there may be some issue with that--but I think Chrome ought to work the same.